# Java "Optimization": if controls in lower classes

Tags: java

Is it better to control variables and parameter "only" (mostly) in the upper areas of the call hierarchy 

or

to save each class individually against wrong parameters, because you don't know who may call it in the future.


I am in the moment a little ambivalent. But i tend to write some more ifs than leave classes unprotected.


What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by control? Can you show us some code?

Comment: "What?" This .. question .. doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: For example, if you have a manager class which delegates calls to subclasses. Most parameters which get to the manager class won't change on the way to the subclasses, so it may be sufficient to control the parameters only in the manager class. Also because you don't expect someone else to call the subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method is part of the public interface of a class (either public or protected)  then you cannot trust the parameters that you are receiving, and therefore you should validate them. On the other hand if the method is private, you are in total control of the arguments you are passing and if you are sure you never pass invalid data then you can safely assume that they are right all the time and avoid any code to validate them.

Now, what exactly is part of the public interface of your system may not be evident to anyone but yourself. Even when a class has public methods, the class where they are declared is totally encapsulated and inaccessible to other users, it may may be impossible to extend it or use it outside a given context, in those cases, your level of encapsulation could help you decide if you are truly in control of what is being passed as parameter and then you can decide if it is safer to validate the data or not in a given context. But in the moment you believe you can lose sight of what is being passed as parameter, then you should validate it, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to sanitizing your parameters or imposing business rules, I think you should apply the same concept behind the expert pattern, i.e. sanitize, impose the rules in the places you have the necessary information/knowledge to do that.

For instance in an MVC application, where the user of an application inserts his age, you can verify that the age is a positive in the controller(it's common sense knowledge that the controller should have) but you can only verify that the user is between specific ages somewhere in the model layer where you have this rule specified.